# what is the need of using function

Tags: functions, notation

I came across a question that we write **y=f(x) , and f(x)=2x+1 , so y=f(x)=2x+1**
then why don't  we simply write **y = 2x+1** .
what is the difference between y=f(x)=2x+1 and y=2x+1

for me , if we write y=2x+1 and put any value of x , we get the result y
same goes for f(x)=2x+1 , so my confusion is , if we are getting   **(y)**   by simply putting the value of **(x)** , then why was the concept of f(x) introduced

Comment: Think at how you would write $\,f(1)+f(2)\,$ using the $\,y\,$ notation.

Comment: The "sum" of the two expressions is useless... We have a function $f(x)$ whose expression is $2x+1$ that means that for every input value assigned to the variable $x$ we can compute the output value of $f(x)$.

Comment: Quite often we want to consider the graph of the function $f(x)$ representing it in the cartesian plane $x-y$: this is the meaning of the  expression $y=2x+1$.

Comment: You can think of $y=f(x)$ as a notation that says $y$ is a dependent variable on $x$, i.e. $y$ is a function of the independent variable $x$.